# Issue uploading image, call to undefined function finfo_buffer()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to upload an image via a script based on Laravel framework and coming across this error:

```
Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\finfo_buffer() 

     * Checks if string contains binary image data
*
* @param mixed $input
* @return boolean
*/
private function isBinary($input)
{
$mime = finfo_buffer(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), (string) $input);
return substr($mime, 0, 4) != 'text';
}
```

I'm not really that well versed on Laravel so would appreciate some help.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You need fileinfo extension enabled for your PHP. See [Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\finfo_buffer()](http://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/131).

> olivervogel commented on May 20:
>
> ext-fileinfo is now required for installation.

Check your php.ini file to see if something along the line of `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` or `extension=fileinfo.so` is commented out. If so uncomment it and restart your web server.

Comment: thanks for response. That is something I dabbled with previously to no success. There is no such line in my php.ini file and when I add one (either extension=php_fileinfo.dll or extension=fileinfo.so) and restart the service, doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you append your post with your environment information? E.g. what OS, web server, PHP version you are using. If you are using XAMPP/MAMP, etc. let us know your version too.

Comment: yes sure. OS: Linux PHP: 5.5.15 Server: Apache HTTP. It's also a VPS if that helps.

Comment: @suge1w, And what distribution? Debian? Ubuntu? Centos?